# Path manipulation

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider you are launching a script in the following linux path:
`/home/chris/sources/a/b/c/d/e/test.py`

I want to be able to check whether folder named `sources` is in path and then return the path `/home/chris/sources/`

Do you think I should do it using simple string manipulation, or do we have in python some xpath library that can help me do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the `os.path` module at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inb4Padraic

```
path = '/home/chris/sources/a/b/c/d/e/test.py'.split('/')
if 'sources' in path:
    print '/'.join(path[:path.index('sources') + 1])
```

another way

```
import os

path = '/home/chris/sources/a/b/c/d/e/test.py'.split('sources')
if len(path) > 1:
    print os.path.join(path[0], 'sources')
```